# For asking more elements than required

Tags: c++

So, I've made this code to input some values on a array, double it then print. The problem is, as far as I can see, there is no errors in code, but when I run it, it keeps me asking to input one more value beyond what I asked (in this case, it asks me 5 values when I need 4. Can someone help me?
(Sorry about bad english :P )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define lim 4

void input(int arr[], int size);
void multiply(int arr[], int size);
void print(int arr[], int size);

int main(){
    int array[lim];

    printf("Insert numbers in array: \n \n");
    input(array,lim);


    multiply(array,lim);

    printf("Printing values after multiplying: \n \n");
    print(array,lim);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void input(int arr[], int size){
    for (int i = 0;i < size; i++){
        scanf("%d \n", &arr[i]);
    }
}

void multiply(int arr[], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] *= 2;
    }
}

void print(int arr[], int size){
    for(int i = 0;i < size; i++){
        printf("%d \n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `\n`-->>> `scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scanf()` function removes whitespaces ***automatically*** before trying to parse things other than characters (`%c`, `%[…]`, `%n`), so you dont have to skip them like you are *trying* to do `%d \n`.

Simply read digits and dont care about them.

```
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
//    ^^^^
```

---

Also you are coding in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), there are different(easier) IO operations, first you have to include `<iostream>`.

Then, for reading you use `std::cin`

```
int i{0};
std::cin >> i;
```

and printing via `std::cout`

```
std::cout << i;
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) you may get extended info about them.

Comment: Ok, its C++, use `cout` for output and `cin` for input

Comment: Thanks! Removing \n worked out.
For the scanf/printf, I was trying to practice then, used to use cin/cout for everything.

Comment: YW. Iam glad it helped you :-)